# Why didn't this give an error?

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

I spent a long time on this.  Why didn't it give some sort of error?  I don't understand:
This java code snipette (I will put comments for code I omitted just for the example):

```
String[] sortOrder = { "Ascending","Descending" }

for ( String order : sortOrder ) {
     if (sortOrder.equals("Ascending")) {
          // code here to sort array in ascending
     } else if ( sortOrder.equals( "Descending") ) {
          // code here to sort descending
     }
}
```

Comment: ... what? You *want* it to give an error?

Comment: What kind of error were you expecting? I mean, other than for the missing semicolon in the first line.

Comment: @user3257891 are you referring to Array of String using .equals() method ?

Comment: You would also want to change `sortOrder.equals("..")` to `order.equals("...")` in your if statements, since you are otherwise comparing string elements and string arrays.

Comment: exactly why it should give an error.

Comment: No I just forgot to put the semicolon in this example.  I was referring to an error inside the for loop.

Comment: @user3257891 No, `equals()` takes an `Object` of any type. If it's the wrong type, it just returns false.

Comment: Thanks.  That led to a lot of confusion.

Comment: @MattCoubrough The OP was expecting calling `foo.equals(bar)`, where `foo` is a string array and `bar` is a string, to result in a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1):

In the javadocs it states:

```
      true if this object is the same as the obj argument; false otherwise.
```

The equals method is returning false instead of an error because your array is not equal to the 
string value of "Ascending" and "Descending"